# How to use rails path helper in cucumber scenario outline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a Cucumber Rails scenario using Scenario Outline

```
Scenario Outline: User can see the logo
  Given I am on the <path>

  Examples:
    | focus_area     | path              |
    | Homepage       | root_path         |
```

This has the steps of

```
Given (/^I am on the ([^"]*)$/) do |path|
  visit path
end
```

When I run this the application attempts to go to /root_path by using this string in the address.

What I actually want is for the helper method to be called so that the path is obtained correctly.

Comment: try using send e.g `visit send(path)`. You might have to use `self.send`

Comment: visit send(path) did the trick.